# Issue git clonning using ssh but works using https

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

When i try cloning public repository hosted on bitbucket using SSH it fails, for instance when i try cloning the following git repository

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:tildeslash/monit.git
```

It gives me this error

```
Cloning into 'monit'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, when i try cloning the same repo using HTTPS

```
git clone https://npmtechnologies@bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit.git
```

It works, what could be the possible issue?

Comment: Go to your profile settings on bitbucket. Check under authentication (or similar) tab. There should be something mentioned about adding your public SSH key there.

Comment: Do we require SSH key for a public repo? it still doesn't make sense because if it requires SSH key it must not allow cloning using HTTPS which is happening in my case.

Comment: @hjpotter92 you are right, by adding SSH key it did work, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https and ssh are two different protocols.

The fact that your **[public key might not be properly registered in your Bitbucket account](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html)** has nothing to do with the https url, which will work.

> if it requires SSH key it must not allow cloning using HTTPS

No: each public repo can be accessed either by ssh or https. One is no more "mandatory" than the other.
If ssh does not work, https will.
Https will require a password only when pushing.
ssh requires that your public key is registered in your Bitbucket account for establishing an authenticated connection.

Comment: Spot on, i just happened to test it once again and by adding SSH key, it does work. thanks.